# How to get Linkedin and Twitter intergration via user profile picture iOS?

Tags: image, profile

I used my app social media linked and Twitter. How do I get the user profile picture in linked and Twitter iOS?

```
NSString *profileImageURLString = [twitteruser valueForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
   NSURL *profileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:profileImageURLString];
    self.twitterimage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:profileUrl];
```

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: NSString *profileImageURLString = [twitteruser valueForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
   NSURL *profileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:profileImageURLString];
    self.twitterimage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:profileUrl];

Comment: Please *[edit] the question* to include your code, not just in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I Got output this code in twitter user profile picture.

NSString *profileImageURLString = [twitteruser valueForKey:@"profile_image_url"];

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[profileImageURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                   NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

twitterimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
```